# Android SDK necessary for react-native app development

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am planning to start react-native app development. I have tried to follow official docs and some other blogs and tutorials but they are not animous on whether we need android SDK for development.

Please tell me can I go ahead with react-native app development without installing android SDK and studio?

Comment: not really. You can develop most of the apps and even create its apk right from expo itself. for some apps where you need to eject and implement some native android feature then you do need an android studio.
if you have good internet connection then you can create apps right from https://snack.expo.io itself

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/) instead, Expo is a framework and a platform for universal react native applications, you will find all what you need to know in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/)

Comment: One more thing to ask: If I am developing app on linux can I run it on ios device by connecting it to my system?

Comment: you can install expo client on your mobile and run apps by scanning the QR code shown in the server console